# Generate a WCF proxy for Silverlight without adding the ASync pattern to the WCF service without hosting the service

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I got a coding scenario I can't seem to fix.
I got a synchronous WCF service and I want to simulate the Add Service Reference (slsvcutil.exe) but without hosting the WCF service. Is this possible?

I want use slsvcutil to generate the client from a wsdl file but it doesn't want to work because it needs an endpoint. Is it possible to generate a WCF proxy for Silverlight without hosting the service and without editting the WCF service by making all calls Asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason you want to generate the proxies without hosting because you don't want to "add the asynch pattern"?

You don't have to edit the WCF service to make it callable asynchronusly, the asynch is all handled by the client not the server.

Take a look at this tutorial and you'll see that the service code doesn't mention asynch at all. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=228

Practically everything in Silverlight is asynchronus and for good reason. It's that way so that the end user doesn't experience blocked UI threads while the app goes off to fetch data.

Comment: Yes I don't want to add the async pattern to my WCF service.
Add service reference creates a client which adds the a sync pattern on the client side. 

I want to simulate this by using slsvcutil.exe but I can't generate a client from a local .wsdl file. It gives me an error message that the endpoint can't be found. So I'm asking if there is a way I can generate a proxy without having an endpoint.

Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, I suspect you'll have to hand craft a WCF client from the classes available in Silverlights runtime. Why don't you want asynch? The main reason to use silverlight IMO is for the improved UX and moving to a synchronus service would be counter to that.

Comment: I don't mind using async at the Silverlight side but I don't want to edit my WCF side just because Silverlight can't create a Proxy without an endpoint.

I think the only way is to make a codegenerator like slsvcutil myself which doesn't need an endpoint.

Comment: I've edited my answer to link you to a service tutorial to illustrate my point that that server side doesn't have anything at all specific to asynchronus calling.

Comment: I know how you can add a service reference without having async calls in WCF. But my problem is that you need to host the service before you can make a proxy.

I want to generate a proxy without hosting the service (by giving the slsvcutil app a .wsdl file)

Comment: Why don't you want to host it? Your service is hosted within an asp.net application, you're gonna have to host it to call it, just run it up and generate the proxies. You're gonna cause yourself a massive ammount of work (writing your own code generator) because you don't want to host your service. Run your asp.net application without debugging so as not to lock any files in your projects and just generate the proxies. Save yourself a million hours of work that slsvcutil has already done for you